# What do bones need to grow outside the body?

Tags: growth, bone

In what environment outside of a living organism can bones grow?

If I were to put an arbitrary human bone in a room and attach a bunch of tubes to it, or dunk it in some kind of solution, where would I have to connect the tubes and what stuff would have to be in the tubes/solution to make the bone grow as if it were inside a living organism?

Comment: Are you counting being sheathed in velvet like an antler as "inside" the body?

Comment: @swbarnes2 Yeah, I forgot to think about antlers, but since they're attached to a body I'm counting them as "inside" the body. I mean I want these bones to grow independent from an animal.